# Re-recording audio vs. convoluting old audio data - differences?

Tags: audio, impulse-response, speech-recognition, speech-processing

I want to transform a studio audio dataset into a smartphone audio dataset (used for a speech recognition application). **Would there be any difference in the resulting audio files using one of the following two aproaches?**

1. Replay all audio files and record with smartphone.
2. Convolute files with smartphone microphone impulse response, assuming the impulse response was determined using the same setup as
       in "1.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would there be any difference in the resulting audio files using one of the following two aproaches?

There would be a difference - probably negligible - which would represent the non-linearity or time-dependence in the system.

Comment: Do you know factors that determine how negligible the non-linearity is?

Answer (score 0):

There would be no difference in the resulting audio files if you take the impulse response from the exactly same setup. This is because the impulse response describes exactly the transformation you would do manually in 1.

Comment: *"There would be no difference in the resulting audio files if you take the impulse response from the exactly same setup."*  are you sure about that??  noise?  (from whatever multiple sources)